# Notepad++ Find lines that contain multiple strings in any combination?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors

For example, in the following list, I want to find all lines that contain `onkey` AND `tur` AND `.pdf`, in **any** combination (stings in any order, repetitions allowed, but each must be present at least once in the line):

```
cat-dog-trutle-horse-horse-monkey.doc
fish-snail-monkey.txt
turtle-zebra-whale-monkey.doc
turtle-zebra-whale-zebra.pdf
turtle-zebra-whale-monkey.pdf
turtle-zebra-whale-monkey.png
turtle-zebra-whale-monkey-monkey.pdf--2
```

The answer should be:

```
turtle-zebra-whale-monkey.pdf
turtle-zebra-whale-monkey-monkey.pdf--2
```

This code does not handle different permutations. Any thoughts how to fix it?

```
(.*)onkey(.*)tur(.*).pdf(.*)
x Regular expression
```

Comment: well, you could add the OR command, and search for three times any of the three so that they would be accepted in any order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use
[*positive lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
(`?=…`) to assert that a given pattern can be matched.
Place the anchor at the beginning of the string and one by one,
in any order, look for a match of each of your strings.

It'll look something like this:

```
^(?=.*onkey)(?=.*tur)(?=.*pdf).*$
```

Ensure you're using the Regular expression mode without
". matches newline".